# Subtracting datetime ranges from other datetime ranges (T-SQL)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, range, subtraction

I need some help to create a SQL query. At least a hint on how to do this.
I have a table Schedule with datetime ranges and another table UnavailableTimes also with datetime ranges. From this I want the available times, by subtracting the unavailable times from the schedule.

**T-SQL (test data)**

```
CREATE TABLE Schedule (
    ID INT,
    StartTime DATETIME,    
    EndTime DATETIME
)

CREATE TABLE UnavailableTimes (
    ID INT,
    StartTime DATETIME,    
    EndTime DATETIME
)

CREATE TABLE AvailableTimes (
    ID INT,
    StartTime DATETIME,    
    EndTime DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO Schedule (ID, StartTime, EndTime)
VALUES 
    (2, '2018-02-27 08:00', '2018-02-27 12:00'),
    (2, '2018-02-27 13:00', '2018-02-27 17:00')

INSERT INTO UnavailableTimes (ID, StartTime, EndTime)
VALUES 
    (2, '2018-02-27 07:30', '2018-02-27 08:30'),
    (2, '2018-02-27 08:00', '2018-02-27 09:30'),
    (2, '2018-02-27 13:30', '2018-02-27 14:00'),
    (2, '2018-02-27 16:00', '2018-02-27 18:00')
```

**Schedule**

```
ID  StartTime           EndTime  
2   2018-02-27 08:00    2018-02-27 12:00  
2   2018-02-27 13:00    2018-02-27 17:00
```

**UnavailableTimes**

```
ID  StartTime           EndTime  
2   2018-02-27 07:30    2018-02-27 08:30  
2   2018-02-27 08:00    2018-02-27 09:30  
2   2018-02-27 13:30    2018-02-27 14:00
2   2018-02-27 16:00    2018-02-27 18:00
```

I want to subtract the time ranges in UnavailableTimes from the time ranges in Schedule to get the available times like this:

**AvailableTimes**

```
ID  StartTime           EndTime  
2   2018-02-27 09:30    2018-02-27 12:00  
2   2018-02-27 13:00    2018-02-27 13:30
2   2018-02-27 14:00    2018-02-27 16:00
```

**EDIT:**
With the help from **MJH** I got the StartTimes and the EndTimes. Now I just need to put this together:

```
;WITH S1 AS (
        SELECT  U.EndTime AS StartTime
        FROM    UnavailableTimes U
        WHERE   NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT  *
                FROM    UnavailableTimes W
                WHERE   U.EndTime BETWEEN W.StartTime AND DATEADD(s, -1, W.EndTime)
        )
        AND EXISTS (
                SELECT  *
                FROM    Schedule S
                WHERE   U.EndTime BETWEEN S.StartTime AND S.EndTime
        )
),
S2 AS (
        SELECT  S.StartTime
        FROM    Schedule S
        WHERE   NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT  *
                FROM    UnavailableTimes U
                WHERE   S.StartTime BETWEEN U.StartTime AND U.EndTime
        )
)
SELECT  StartTime
FROM    S1
UNION ALL
SELECT  StartTime
FROM    S2
ORDER BY 1


;WITH S1 AS (
        SELECT  U.StartTime AS EndTime
        FROM    UnavailableTimes U
        WHERE   NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT  *
                FROM    UnavailableTimes W
                WHERE   U.StartTime BETWEEN DATEADD(s, 1, W.StartTime) AND W.EndTime
        )
        AND EXISTS (
                SELECT  *
                FROM    Schedule S
                WHERE   U.StartTime BETWEEN S.StartTime AND S.EndTime
        )
),
S2 AS (
        SELECT  S.EndTime
        FROM    Schedule S
        WHERE   NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT  *
                FROM    UnavailableTimes U
                WHERE   S.EndTime BETWEEN U.StartTime AND U.EndTime
        )
)
SELECT  EndTime
FROM    S1
UNION ALL
SELECT  EndTime
FROM    S2
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: which db you are using

Comment: SQL Server (T-SQL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's good, the final part of the puzzle is stitching it all together:

```
;WITH S1 AS (
        SELECT  U.EndTime AS StartTime
        FROM    UnavailableTimes U
        WHERE   NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT  *
                FROM    UnavailableTimes W
                WHERE   U.EndTime BETWEEN W.StartTime AND DATEADD(s, -1, W.EndTime)
        )
        AND EXISTS (
                SELECT  *
                FROM    Schedule S
                WHERE   U.EndTime BETWEEN S.StartTime AND S.EndTime
        )
),
S2 AS (
        SELECT  S.StartTime
        FROM    Schedule S
        WHERE   NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT  *
                FROM    UnavailableTimes U
                WHERE   S.StartTime BETWEEN U.StartTime AND U.EndTime
        )
),
S3 AS (
        SELECT  StartTime
        FROM    S1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  StartTime
        FROM    S2
),
S AS (
        SELECT  StartTime, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY StartTime) RN
        FROM    S3
),
E1 AS (
        SELECT  U.StartTime AS EndTime
        FROM    UnavailableTimes U
        WHERE   NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT  *
                FROM    UnavailableTimes W
                WHERE   U.StartTime BETWEEN DATEADD(s, 1, W.StartTime) AND W.EndTime
        )
        AND EXISTS (
                SELECT  *
                FROM    Schedule S
                WHERE   U.StartTime BETWEEN S.StartTime AND S.EndTime
        )
),
E2 AS (
        SELECT  S.EndTime
        FROM    Schedule S
        WHERE   NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT  *
                FROM    UnavailableTimes U
                WHERE   S.EndTime BETWEEN U.StartTime AND U.EndTime
        )
),
E3 AS (
        SELECT  EndTime
        FROM    E1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  EndTime
        FROM    E2
),
E AS (
        SELECT  EndTime, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY EndTime) RN
        FROM    E3
)
SELECT  S.StartTime, E.EndTime
FROM    S INNER JOIN E
        ON S.RN = E.RN
ORDER BY S.RN
```

Comment: Thank you again. I couldn't figure out how to get them in the right order. "ROW_NUMBER() OVER" was the answer, I've never used that before.

Comment: You're welcome, at this point I should probably point out that this solution would probably not "scale" very well, if you are thinking about putting something like this into a commercial product then it would make more sense to have a calendar table with all the time increments you need (e.g. every 15 minutes) and link to that.  Then it would be fairly easy to get the time slots not in use.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a crack at the start times for you, you should be able to work out how to do the EndTimes yourself:

```
;WITH S1 AS (
        SELECT  U.EndTime AS StartTime
        FROM    UnavailableTimes U
        WHERE   NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT  *
                FROM    UnavailableTimes W
                WHERE   U.EndTime BETWEEN W.StartTime AND DATEADD(s, -1, W.EndTime)
        )
        AND EXISTS (
                SELECT  *
                FROM    Schedule S
                WHERE   U.EndTime BETWEEN S.StartTime AND S.EndTime
        )
),
S2 AS (
        SELECT  S.StartTime
        FROM    Schedule S
        WHERE   NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT  *
                FROM    UnavailableTimes U
                WHERE   S.StartTime BETWEEN U.StartTime AND U.EndTime
        )
)
SELECT  StartTime
FROM    S1
UNION ALL
SELECT  StartTime
FROM    S2
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: Thank you. This was really helpful. I was able to do the EndTimes myself.